# Is `??` thread safe in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Simple question:
Are "`??`" and "`?.`" and "`? :`" thread-safe? And can I trust them? Or I should use other thread-safety solutions?
For instance this code:

```
public static T Instance => _Instance ?? (_Instance = CreateInstance());
```

is thread-safe?

Comment: Your question here shouldn't be if `??` is thread safe, it should be wether `CreateInstance()` is.

Comment: Well, if you assume that `CreateInstance()` IS threadsafe, you still need to ask if the `??` expression would be threadsafe.

Comment: @InBetween let's suppose that `CreateInstance()` is thread-safe. I want to focus on `??`

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes `CreateInstance()` is thread-safe. What about `??`?

Comment: `?.` is a very different kettle of fish. But not applicable to your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not threadsafe, due to a race condition. (e.g Thread A checks value, finds it null, thread B checks value, finds it null, thread B initialises value with call to CreateInstance(), thread A intialises value with call to CreateInstance().)

The correct approach to the threadsafe initialisation of a singleton is to use the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class, for example:

```
public T Instance => _instance.Value;

static Lazy<T> _instance = new Lazy<T>(CreateInstance);
```

where `CreateInstance()` returns an instance of type `T`.

Comment: Should I use `lock` in `CreateInstance()`?

Comment: @MohammadMirMostafa, it won't help, as you need to synchronize access to both: condition (`??`) and assignment (`CreateInstance()`). Rather use `Lazy<>` it [does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs,381) all synchronization properly for you.

Comment: @MohammadMirMostafa If it can be called from more than one thread, and if doing so could cause a problem, then yes - but it is not possible for me to tell without seeing its implementation. Note that if the only place it is called is from the `Lazy` object, then you definitely don't need to lock it.

Answer (score 2):

`??` will read a reference which is guaranteed to be atomic in C# (writes are too). So if your question is wether you can have torn reference reads or writes in C#, the answer is no.

Now, does that make `public static T Instance => _Instance ?? (_Instance = CreateInstance());` threadsafe? The general answer is no, becuase that expression has one read and one write, which is most definitely not an atomic operation.

Things that can go wrong:

1. Race condition reading `_Instance`: One thread can read it as `null` just before a second one initializes it. You end up running `CreateInstance()` twice. Is that a problem? If it is, then its not threadsafe. If its not, then it *could* be threadsafe, not optimal from a performance point of view, but possibly safe.
2. What about concurrent executions of `CreateInstance()`? Is that scenario safe? Due to the previous race condition, it is also possible that one thread enters `CreateInstance` before another one exits. Now your problem is not onlty that `CreateInstance` runs twice, but that both (or more) run concurrently. Is that safe?

So in general, this is as safe as how safe `CreateInstance()` is.

Comment: Agreed. It is NOT threadsafe, and in particular that race condition is a nasty one if you don't want to call `CreateInstance()` twice.